# pycord get interaction without resending or editing message after restart

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

im currently working on a selfroles bot for my server and i got this problem everytim i restart the bot the message with the button to click has to be edited or resend to make the button work again or else it will just say "This interaction failed".

This is the code for my button:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(
    description="Title"
                "Description"
)
requestbutton = discord.ui.Button(
    label="make a request"
)

async def requestcallback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    modal = RequestModal()
    await interaction.response.send_modal(modal)

requestbutton.callback = requestcallback

view = discord.ui.View()
view.timeout = None

view.add_item(requestbutton)

            
await requestschannel.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

Is it possible to get the button to work again after a restart without resending or editing the message?

Comment: check the examples https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using [PersistentViews](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py).

Examples at:
https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/blob/master/examples/views/persistent.py